# Build Static Library in Xcode 4.6 for Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

How to build a static library for simulator on **Xcode 4.6**?

I've tried "https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework". But got an error while using that framework on demo.

Error is like:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/shuvo/test_lib/Demo(V.1)/myProject.lib/libMyProjectLibrary.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/shuvo/test_lib/Demo(V.1)/myProject.lib/libMyProjectLibrary.a (2 slices)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     **"_OBJC_CLASS_$_showScreen", referenced from:**
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Comment: Looks like you are doing more than just building a static library if the linker is involved.  I suspect you have 2 projects (one a static library and the other an app) and the static library is a dependency of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same problem,and solve it by setting the static lib's run configuration as Release in the scheme editor.

here is the words in the document of iOS-Universal-Framework, section "Building your iOS Framework":

> step 2.(optional) Set the "Run" configuration in the scheme editor.
>   It's set to Debug by default but you'll probably want to change it to
>   "Release" when you're ready to distribute your framework.

the key is the "Build Active Architecture Only" in Build Settings,
Debug is set to NO by default