# Error after applying custom framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks

First of all, I have built a custom universal framework successfully.

Inside the framework, I have references to other 3rd party library and framework. I believe when I link this custom framework to other project, I need to set up the reference for those 3rd party resources.

Now the problem is, when I link this "MyCustomFramework" to my project, it's having 
:

`undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_environ", referenced from:
   _GenerateEntropicChaos in MyCustomFramework`

I learned the error usually caused by library search path issue. Since this error is point to the Framework, so is it the current project path is wrong or the project that build this framework is wrong? It seems like all the 3rd party also having this undefined symbols issue.

Comment: In your custom framework. `Project > Build Settings > Build Active Architectures Only > NO` for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809825/build-static-library-in-xcode-4-6-for-simulator

Comment: sbarow thanks for the reply, i have tried this solution before, but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's reate to simulator or real machine, so try following:
first choose target to simulator and build your framework.
second choose target to real machin , build another framework

then link these two framework seprately to you project. and see what will happen.